# WP: shortcodes when using if(have_posts()) followed by while(have_posts())

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to minimize my code and have put together this little snippet, it doesn't seem to work however. What am I missing?

```
query_posts( 'year=2011' );
if ( have_posts() );
while ( have_posts() );
echo 'test';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is the question mark at the end of the if and at the end of while. IMy opinion is that you need a colon ":"

```
query_posts( 'year=2011' );
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        echo 'test';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!
Note to self: also make sure to include the_post() after the while statement otherwise you'll end up with an infinite loop...